# Update Circle kwargs on TextInput change

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to update the kwargs of the Circles from my `bokeh.plotting.figure` on a `TextInput` value change.

I have a data source with a column "text" and I want to highlight all the data points for which the corresponding "text" startswith the `TextInput.value`. My code looks like this:

```
def bundler_text(path):
    def bkapp(doc):
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        columns = df.columns

        def filter_input(attr, old, new):
            """"""
            global highlighted_idx
            subset = df[df["text"].str.startswith(filter_inp.value)]
            highlighted_idx = subset.index.tolist()
            
            ## Set alpha to 0.1 for ids not in highlighted_idx and to 1 for the others
            ...

        source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
        circle_kwargs = {"x": "x", "y": "y", "size": 1, "alpha": 1, "source": source}
        data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=800)

        p = figure()
        scatter = p.circle(**circle_kwargs)

        filter_inp = TextInput(value="", title="Filter...")
        filter_inp.on_change("value", filter_input)

        return doc.add_root(
            row(p, column(filter_inp, data_table))
        )
    return bkapp
```

I have tried a bunch of different approaches but I am not able to access and modify the attributes of my circles. Does anybody have any recommendation on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `MultiChoice` instead of the `TextInput` to filter the selections.

The idea is to have a valid `ColumnDataSource` and adapt the values for `size` and `alpha` using a `CustomJS` section. If a category is selected, the alpha value is set to 1 and the size increases to 12. Else the values are set to the default value again.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, MultiChoice
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'y':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'type':['boy', 'girl', 'boy', 'girl', 'girl'],
    'alpha':0.5,
    'size':10
})

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(width=300, height=300)
p.circle(x='x', y='y', alpha='alpha', size='size', source=source)

# Our MultiChoice widget accepts the values in the "type" column
mc = MultiChoice(title='Filter', options=list(df['type'].unique()), width=300)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, mc=mc),
    code="""
    const data = source.data;
    var size = data['size']
    var alpha = data['alpha']
    var type = data['type']

    for(var i=0; i<size.length; i++){
        if(mc.value.includes(type[i])){
            size[i] = 12
            alpha[i] = 1
        }
        else{
            size[i] = 10
            alpha[i] = 0.5
        }
    }
    source.change.emit()
    """
)
mc.js_on_change('value', callback)
show(column(mc, p))
```

### Output

[image: active filter sets alpha value to 1]